# jQuery Mobile: how to create dynamic pages from a string template?

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, render, dynamic-pages

Hi to everyone this is my first question in stackoverflow. I'll try to create a Single Page Web App with jQuery Mobile (for the UI) and PhoneGap (because I want it cross-platform). In my app I want to create pages via some templates (string) and, whene i click on a button or a list element, the app create the corresponding page from the template and navigate it by the # attr. Whene I load the template the first time jqm render the page in the right way, but when I remove it from the DOM and append it when I need the page, the jqm don't render the page with its style, but I see only the link (or other elements). Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

By default jQuery Mobile will auto enhance the appropriate markup on your page, however if you add dynamic content later you will need to manually trigger the `create` event on your new page.

For example

```
$('#newPageID').trigger('create');
```

From the [Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (listview button, select, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no matter what is said in official jQuery Mobile documentation method .trigger('create') can not restyle full page.

Instead this should be used:

```
$('#newPageID').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vN45m/

It can be testes easily, just replace pagecreate with create or comment that full line.